# Is it possible to recreate this image in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, plot, graphs

I'm trying to create a series of figures in the below format, and would like to see if there's a way to do this in latex instead of my current fiddly and time consuming method, which uses an external graphing program to create a pdf image that I simply load in to my latex document using a graphics package.

[image: example]

The central graph is a simple jpg, while the rest of the data used is in a dat file. All horizontal axes have the same values and dimensions, and likewise all vertical axes have the same values and dimensions.

Is it possible for latex to plot all this together in a format that matches the shown figure?

Comment: Yes. `pgfplots` should be able to handle that easily. The `groupplots` library (part of `pgfplots`) might be useful.

Comment: @Werner could you please delete the image you added. By uploading my image in that manner stackexchange puts a creative commons licence on it, which I didn't want to do to my data, hence why I uploaded it offsite.

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but doesn't uploading to imgur give them lots of license too? ([TOS](http://imgur.com/tos))

Comment: On-topic: pgfplots

Comment: @Ulysses: Furthermore, I'm assuming you want to remove this image once you're satisfied that your question is answered. At that point, this question becomes useless (despite the current answer), because no-one would be able to view the output you want and with a title requesting to "recreate this image", it doesn't provide any value to future visitors. If this is the case, your question will most likely be subject to closure as being "unclear what is being asked".

Comment: The issue is that by uploading it here it gets a creative commons licence stamped on it, which I don't want. By uploading to imgur I can place a much stricter licence on it. Creative commons means anyone can use it for literally anything.

Comment: @Ulysses: See [Delete uploaded image](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250344/168244).

Comment: I was never planning on removing my own uploaded image. I don't mind people seeing it. The issue was purely that I didn't want to release it under CC. Regardless, I've added a mock image to the question to resolve the issue of offsite hosting. I'm now just waiting on a mod to delete the image Werner added.

Comment: @Joseph Wright You've removed the wrong image. Could you please roll back the edit to return the mock image I added, and instead manually delete the image Werner added in revision 2.

Comment: @Ulysses The only version I see that had an image in the post was revision 3: revisions 1 and 2 link to images but don't contain them ...

Comment: The revision seems to have now been modified, although the image still exists. This is what I want deleted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSlkS.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proof of concept.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y
0 1
2 1
3 3
4 5
5 2
6 1.5
7 1
8 0
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
 group style={
   group size=2 by 2,
   vertical sep=0pt,
   horizontal sep=0pt
 },
 width=8cm,height=8cm,
 xmin=0,xmax=8,
 ymin=0,ymax=8]

\nextgroupplot[
   xtick pos=right,
   ylabel=Something,
   xlabel=Other]
\addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=8,ymin=0,ymax=8] {example-image-1x1};

\nextgroupplot[
  width=3cm,height=8cm,
  x post scale=-1,
  ytick pos=right,
  xtick=\empty,
  xlabel=Intensity,
  ylabel=Something]

\addplot table[x=y,y=x] {data.dat};

\nextgroupplot[
  height=3cm,width=8cm,
  ytick=\empty,
  ylabel=Intensity,
  xlabel=Other]
\addplot table[x=x,y=y] {data.dat};

\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This should be enough to get me started. I'll give this a go and see if I can get everything working. :D